# GMP Compilation for NDK error: Oops, mp_limb_t is 64 bits, but the assembler code in this configuration expects 32 bits

Tags: android, gmp

I am running Arch Linux on a 64 bit system.

I try to follow these instructions:

```
# download gmp, unpack
cd $NDK_ROOT/sources
wget ftp://ftp.gmplib.org/pub/gmp-4.2.4/gmp-4.2.4.tar.bz2
tar -jxvf gmp-4.2.4.tar.bz2
mv gmp-4.2.4 gmp

cd gmp
CFLAGS=-UHAVE_LOCALE_H ./configure --host=arm-unknown-linux --prefix=$SYSROOT/usr 
make
make install
```

Found [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/User:Dbright/Android_compile); however, I get the error (At this point I have no clue, if all output is relevant. I apologize, if it's too much):

```
[jav@jav gmp]$ CFLAGS=-UHAVE_LOCALE_H ./configure --host=arm-unknown-linux --prefix=$SYSROOT/usr
configure: WARNING: If you wanted to set the --build type, don't use --host.
    If a cross compiler is detected then cross compile mode will be used.
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... arm-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for arm-unknown-linux-strip... no
checking for strip... strip
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking ABI=standard
checking compiler arm-unknown-linux-gcc -UHAVE_LOCALE_H ... no
checking compiler gcc -UHAVE_LOCALE_H ... yes
checking whether ARM gcc unsigned division works... yes
checking for arm-unknown-linux-gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ANSI C... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking build system compiler gcc... yes
checking for build system preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for build system executable suffix... 
checking whether build system compiler is ANSI... yes
checking for build system compiler math library... -lm
checking for egrep... grep -E
using ABI="standard"
      CC="gcc"
      CFLAGS="-UHAVE_LOCALE_H"
      CPPFLAGS=""
      MPN_PATH=" arm generic"
checking for function prototypes... yes
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking whether assembler supports --noexecstack option... yes
checking for arm-unknown-linux-ar... no
checking for ar... ar
checking for BSD-compatible nm... nm
checking for BSD-compatible nm... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking dlfcn.h usability... yes
checking dlfcn.h presence... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for objdir... .libs
checking for arm-unknown-linux-ar... ar
checking for arm-unknown-linux-ranlib... no
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for arm-unknown-linux-strip... strip
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
configure: creating libtool
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking whether time.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes
checking fcntl.h usability... yes
checking fcntl.h presence... yes
checking for fcntl.h... yes
checking float.h usability... yes
checking float.h presence... yes
checking for float.h... yes
checking invent.h usability... no
checking invent.h presence... no
checking for invent.h... no
checking langinfo.h usability... yes
checking langinfo.h presence... yes
checking for langinfo.h... yes
checking locale.h usability... yes
checking locale.h presence... yes
checking for locale.h... yes
checking nl_types.h usability... yes
checking nl_types.h presence... yes
checking for nl_types.h... yes
checking sys/attributes.h usability... no
checking sys/attributes.h presence... no
checking for sys/attributes.h... no
checking sys/iograph.h usability... no
checking sys/iograph.h presence... no
checking for sys/iograph.h... no
checking sys/mman.h usability... yes
checking sys/mman.h presence... yes
checking for sys/mman.h... yes
checking sys/param.h usability... yes
checking sys/param.h presence... yes
checking for sys/param.h... yes
checking sys/processor.h usability... no
checking sys/processor.h presence... no
checking for sys/processor.h... no
checking sys/pstat.h usability... no
checking sys/pstat.h presence... no
checking for sys/pstat.h... no
checking sys/sysinfo.h usability... yes
checking sys/sysinfo.h presence... yes
checking for sys/sysinfo.h... yes
checking sys/syssgi.h usability... no
checking sys/syssgi.h presence... no
checking for sys/syssgi.h... no
checking sys/systemcfg.h usability... no
checking sys/systemcfg.h presence... no
checking for sys/systemcfg.h... no
checking sys/time.h usability... yes
checking sys/time.h presence... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking sys/times.h usability... yes
checking sys/times.h presence... yes
checking for sys/times.h... yes
checking for sys/resource.h... yes
checking for sys/sysctl.h... yes
checking for machine/hal_sysinfo.h... no
checking whether fgetc is declared... yes
checking whether fscanf is declared... yes
checking whether optarg is declared... yes
checking whether ungetc is declared... yes
checking whether vfprintf is declared... yes
checking whether sys_errlist is declared... yes
checking whether sys_nerr is declared... yes
checking return type of signal handlers... void
checking for intmax_t... yes
checking for long double... yes
checking for long long... yes
checking for ptrdiff_t... yes
checking for quad_t... yes
checking for uint_least32_t... yes
checking for preprocessor stringizing operator... yes
checking for working volatile... yes
checking whether <stdarg.h> exists and works... yes
checking whether gcc __attribute__ ((const)) works... yes
checking whether gcc __attribute__ ((malloc)) works... yes
checking whether gcc __attribute__ ((mode (XX))) works... yes
checking whether gcc __attribute__ ((noreturn)) works... yes
checking for inline... inline
checking for cos in -lm... yes
checking for working alloca.h... yes
checking for alloca (via gmp-impl.h)... yes
checking how to allocate temporary memory... alloca
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking format of `double' floating point... IEEE little endian
checking for alarm... yes
checking for attr_get... no
checking for clock... yes
checking for clock_gettime... yes
checking for cputime... no
checking for getpagesize... yes
checking for getrusage... yes
checking for gettimeofday... yes
checking for getsysinfo... no
checking for localeconv... yes
checking for memset... yes
checking for mmap... yes
checking for mprotect... yes
checking for nl_langinfo... yes
checking for obstack_vprintf... yes
checking for popen... yes
checking for processor_info... no
checking for pstat_getprocessor... no
checking for raise... yes
checking for read_real_time... no
checking for sigaction... yes
checking for sigaltstack... yes
checking for sigstack... yes
checking for syssgi... no
checking for strchr... yes
checking for strerror... yes
checking for strnlen... yes
checking for strtol... yes
checking for strtoul... yes
checking for sysconf... yes
checking for sysctl... yes
checking for sysctlbyname... no
checking for times... yes
checking for vsnprintf... yes
checking whether vsnprintf works... yes
checking whether sscanf needs writable input... no
checking for struct pst_processor.psp_iticksperclktick... no
checking for suitable m4... m4
checking if m4wrap produces spurious output... no
checking how to switch to text section... .text
checking how to switch to data section... .data
checking for assembler label suffix... :
checking for assembler global directive... .globl
checking for assembler global directive attribute... 
checking if globals are prefixed by underscore... no
checking how to switch to read-only data section...     .section    .rodata
checking for assembler .type directive... .type $1,@$2
checking for assembler .size directive... .size $1,$2
checking for assembler local label prefix... .L
checking for assembler byte directive... .byte
checking how to define a 32-bit word... .long
checking if .align assembly directive is logarithmic... no
checking for unsigned short... yes
checking size of unsigned short... 2
checking for unsigned... yes
checking size of unsigned... 4
checking for unsigned long... yes
checking size of unsigned long... 8
checking for mp_limb_t... yes
checking size of mp_limb_t... 8
configure: error: Oops, mp_limb_t is 64 bits, but the assembler code
in this configuration expects 32 bits.
You appear to have set $CFLAGS, perhaps you also need to tell GMP the
intended ABI, see "ABI and ISA" in the manual.
```

Some solutions state that changing 'CFLAGS' to 'CFLAGS=-O2' fixes the issue; however, the error I get is identical to one using 'CFLAGS=-UHAVE_LOCALE_H'.

Other state that manually setting 'ABI=32' right after './configure' fixes the issue, but I obtain.
Link here https://gmplib.org/list-archives/gmp-discuss/2012-May/005043.html

```
If a cross compiler is detected then cross compile mode will be used.
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... arm-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for arm-unknown-linux-strip... no
checking for strip... strip
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
configure: error: ABI=32 is not among the following valid choices: standard
```

The only ABI obtain I have is standard. :/
Also, in the same link [2], people say that the flag -m32 fixes the issue, but 
I get the error

```
[jav@jav gmp]$ CFLAGS=-m32 ./configure --host=arm-unknown-linux --prefix=$SYSROOT/usr
configure: WARNING: If you wanted to set the --build type, don't use --host.
    If a cross compiler is detected then cross compile mode will be used.
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... arm-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for arm-unknown-linux-strip... no
checking for strip... strip
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking ABI=standard
checking compiler arm-unknown-linux-gcc -m32 ... no
checking compiler gcc -m32 ... no
checking compiler arm-unknown-linux-cc -m32 ... no
checking whether cc is gcc... yes
checking compiler cc -m32 ... no
configure: error: could not find a working compiler, see config.log for details
```

Update August 6th:
Based on Marc's suggestion. I set the preliminary variables, but I obtain the following:

```
[jav@jav ~]$ $NDKROOT_64_r9c/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh --platform=android-9 --install-dir=$NDKROOT_64_r9c/arm-linux-androideabi/
Auto-config: --toolchain=arm-linux-androideabi-4.6
Copying prebuilt binaries...
Copying sysroot headers and libraries...
Copying libstdc++ headers and libraries...
Copying files to: /home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/
Cleaning up...
Done.
[jav@jav ~]$ export CC="$NDKROOT_
$NDKROOT_32_r10  $NDKROOT_64_r9c  
[jav@jav ~]$ export CC="$NDKROOT_64_r9c/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=$NDKROOT_64_r9c/arm-linux-androideabi/sysroot"
[jav@jav ~]$ export CXX="$NDKROOT_64_r9c/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ --sysroot=$NDKROOT_64_r9c/arm-linux-androideabi/sysroot"
[jav@jav ~]$ $CXX
arm-linux-androideabi-g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
[jav@jav ~]$ export AR="$NDKROOT_64_r9c/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar"
[jav@jav ~]$ export SYSROOT="$NDKROOT_64_r9c/arm-linux-androideabi/sysroot"
[jav@jav ~]$ export PATH="$NDKROOT_64_r9c/arm-linux-androideabi/bin":$PATH
[jav@jav ~]$ cd android-ndk-r9c_64/
[jav@jav android-ndk-r9c_64]$ cd sources/
[jav@jav sources]$ cd gmp
[jav@jav gmp]$ CFLAGS=-UHAVE_LOCALE_H ./configure --host=arm-unknown-linux --prefix=$SYSROOT/usr
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... arm-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for arm-unknown-linux-strip... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking ABI=standard
checking whether /home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/sysroot is gcc... yes
checking compiler /home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/sysroot -UHAVE_LOCALE_H ... yes
checking whether ARM gcc unsigned division works... yes
checking for arm-unknown-linux-gcc... /home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/sysroot
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... yes
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether /home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/sysroot accepts -g... yes
checking for /home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/sysroot option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for /home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/sysroot option to accept ISO C99... -std=gnu99
checking for /home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/sysroot -std=gnu99 option to accept ISO Standard C... (cached) -std=gnu99
checking how to run the C preprocessor... /home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/sysroot -std=gnu99 -E
checking build system compiler /home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/sysroot -std=gnu99... no
checking build system compiler /home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/sysroot -std=gnu99 -UHAVE_LOCALE_H ... no
checking build system compiler cc... no
checking build system compiler gcc... no
checking build system compiler c89... no
checking build system compiler c99... no
configure: error: Cannot find a build system compiler
```

It is clear that the compiler cc, gcc, c89, and c99 is not there, but I have no clue how to fix this.

Now, If I use -m32 in CFLAGS, I get:

```
[jav@jav gmp]$ CFLAGS=-m32 ./configure --host=arm-unknown-linux --prefix=$SYSROOT/usr
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... arm-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for arm-unknown-linux-strip... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking ABI=standard
checking whether /home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/sysroot is gcc... yes
checking compiler /home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/sysroot -m32 ... no
configure: error: could not find a working compiler, see config.log for details
```

And, my config.log:
Invocation command line was

```
  $ ./configure --host=arm-unknown-linux --prefix=/home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/sysroot/usr

PATH: /home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/bin
PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /usr/bin/vendor_perl
PATH: /usr/bin/core_perl{PATH}
PATH: /home/jav/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64/sdk/platform-tools{PATH}
PATH: /home/jav/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64/sdk/tools{PATH}
PATH: /home/jav/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64/sdk/platform-tools{PATH}
PATH: /home/jav/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64/sdk/tools

## Core tests. ##

configure:3040: checking build system type
configure:3054: result: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
configure:3074: checking host system type
configure:3087: result: arm-unknown-linux-gnu
configure:3124: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:3192: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:3203: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:3253: result: yes
configure:3302: checking for arm-unknown-linux-strip
configure:3332: result: no
configure:3342: checking for strip
configure:3358: found /home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/strip
configure:3369: result: strip
configure:3394: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
configure:3433: result: /usr/bin/mkdir -p
configure:3446: checking for gawk
configure:3462: found /usr/bin/gawk
configure:3473: result: gawk
configure:3484: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:3506: result: yes
configure:3589: checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles
configure:3598: result: no
User:
ABI=
CC=/home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/sysroot
CFLAGS=-m32
CPPFLAGS=(unset)
MPN_PATH=
GMP:
abilist=standard
cclist=gcc cc
configure:5546: /home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/sysroot -c conftest.c >&5
configure:5549: $? = 0
configure:5552: checking whether /home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/sysroot is gcc
configure:5554: result: yes
configure:5568: /home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/sysroot 2>&1 | grep xlc >/dev/null
configure:5571: $? = 1
configure:5625: checking compiler /home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/sysroot -m32 
Test compile: 
configure:5639: /home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/sysroot -m32  conftest.c >&5
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option '-m32'
configure:5642: $? = 1
failed program was:

int main () { return 0; }
configure:6665: result: no
configure:6903: error: could not find a working compiler, see config.log for details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
ac_cv_env_ABI_set=
ac_cv_env_ABI_value=
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_FOR_BUILD_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_FOR_BUILD_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=set
ac_cv_env_CC_value='/home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/sysroot'
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=-m32
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_FOR_BUILD_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_FOR_BUILD_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=set
ac_cv_env_CXX_value='/home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ --sysroot=/home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/sysroot'
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_M4_set=
ac_cv_env_M4_value=
ac_cv_env_YACC_set=
ac_cv_env_YACC_value=
ac_cv_env_YFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_YFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=set
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=arm-unknown-linux
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=arm-unknown-linux-gnu
ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_path_mkdir=/usr/bin/mkdir
ac_cv_prog_AWK=gawk
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_STRIP=strip
ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=yes

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ABI=''
ACLOCAL='${SHELL} /home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/sources/gmp/missing --run aclocal-1.11'
AMTAR='$${TAR-tar}'
AR='/home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar'
AS=''
ASMFLAGS=''
AUTOCONF='${SHELL} /home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/sources/gmp/missing --run autoconf'
AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} /home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/sources/gmp/missing --run autoheader'
AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} /home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/sources/gmp/missing --run automake-1.11'
AWK='gawk'
CALLING_CONVENTIONS_OBJS='arm32call.lo arm32check.lo'
CC='/home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/sysroot'
CCAS=''
CC_FOR_BUILD=''
CFLAGS='-m32'
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CPP_FOR_BUILD=''
CXX='/home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ --sysroot=/home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/sysroot'
CXXCPP=''
CXXFLAGS=''
CYGPATH_W='echo'
DEFN_LONG_LONG_LIMB=''
DEFS=''
DLLTOOL=''
DSYMUTIL=''
DUMPBIN=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
ENABLE_STATIC_FALSE=''
ENABLE_STATIC_TRUE=''
EXEEXT=''
EXEEXT_FOR_BUILD=''
FGREP=''
GMP_LDFLAGS=''
GMP_LIMB_BITS=''
GMP_NAIL_BITS='0'
GREP=''
HAVE_CLOCK_01=''
HAVE_CPUTIME_01=''
HAVE_GETRUSAGE_01=''
HAVE_GETTIMEOFDAY_01=''
HAVE_HOST_CPU_FAMILY_power='0'
HAVE_HOST_CPU_FAMILY_powerpc='0'
HAVE_SIGACTION_01=''
HAVE_SIGALTSTACK_01=''
HAVE_SIGSTACK_01=''
HAVE_STACK_T_01=''
HAVE_SYS_RESOURCE_H_01=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='$(install_sh) -c -s'
LD=''
LDFLAGS=''
LEX=''
LEXLIB=''
LEX_OUTPUT_ROOT=''
LIBCURSES=''
LIBGMPXX_LDFLAGS=''
LIBGMP_DLL=''
LIBGMP_LDFLAGS=''
LIBM=''
LIBM_FOR_BUILD=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBREADLINE=''
LIBS=''
LIBTOOL=''
LIPO=''
LN_S=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
M4=''
MAINT='#'
MAINTAINER_MODE_FALSE=''
MAINTAINER_MODE_TRUE='#'
MAKEINFO='${SHELL} /home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/sources/gmp/missing --run makeinfo'
MANIFEST_TOOL=''
MKDIR_P='/usr/bin/mkdir -p'
NM=''
NMEDIT=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJEXT=''
OTOOL64=''
OTOOL=''
PACKAGE='gmp'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='gmp-bugs@gmplib.org, see https://gmplib.org/manual/Reporting-Bugs.html'
PACKAGE_NAME='GNU MP'
PACKAGE_STRING='GNU MP 6.0.0'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='gmp'
PACKAGE_URL='http://www.gnu.org/software/gmp/'
PACKAGE_VERSION='6.0.0'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
RANLIB=''
SED=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/sh'
SPEED_CYCLECOUNTER_OBJ=''
STRIP='strip'
TAL_OBJECT=''
TUNE_LIBS=''
TUNE_SQR_OBJ=''
U_FOR_BUILD=''
VERSION='6.0.0'
WANT_CXX_FALSE=''
WANT_CXX_TRUE=''
WITH_READLINE_01=''
YACC=''
YFLAGS=''
ac_ct_AR=''
ac_ct_CC=''
ac_ct_CXX=''
ac_ct_DUMPBIN=''
am__EXEEXT_FALSE=''
am__EXEEXT_TRUE=''
am__isrc=''
am__leading_dot='.'
am__tar='$${TAR-tar} chof - "$$tardir"'
am__untar='$${TAR-tar} xf -'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='linux-gnu'
build_vendor='unknown'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
gmp_srclinks=''
host='arm-unknown-linux-gnu'
host_alias='arm-unknown-linux'
host_cpu='arm'
host_os='linux-gnu'
host_vendor='unknown'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
install_sh='${SHELL} /home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/sources/gmp/install-sh'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
mkdir_p='/usr/bin/mkdir -p'
mpn_objects=''
mpn_objs_in_libgmp=''
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/home/jav/android-ndk-r9c_64/arm-linux-androideabi/sysroot/usr'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "GNU MP"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "gmp"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "6.0.0"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "GNU MP 6.0.0"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "gmp-bugs@gmplib.org, see https://gmplib.org/manual/Reporting-Bugs.html"
#define PACKAGE_URL "http://www.gnu.org/software/gmp/"
#define PACKAGE "gmp"
#define VERSION "6.0.0"
#define WANT_ASSEMBLY 1
#define WANT_FFT 1
#define HAVE_HOST_CPU_arm 1

configure: exit 1
```

Help please.

Comment: GMP 4.2.4 might now be too old for the latest Android versions, and you won't get any support upstream. Try the latest GMP version (6.0.0).

Comment: You need a cross-compiler to cross-compile...

Comment: @vinc17: I get the same output as in gmp4.2.4

Comment: @MarcGlisse: I thought that the first link I posted contained all the information I needed. So, how can I successfully call this cross-compiler?

Comment: You seem to have skipped the preliminaries in that link: `export CC=...` etc.

Comment: Thanks, Marc. Please see update above.

Comment: I still can't find an answer... can anyone help?

Comment: @knowNothing: found a fix? I just encountered the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is your --host value is wrong. arm-unknown-linux means you want your gmp to be used on a 32 bit arm linux.If you are cross-compiling for a 64bit arm android , the right host is aarch64-linux-android.

Comment: This is a very helpful answer because on my `Windows 7 msys2` environment,  I had the same sort of error and after checking the `--host` variable, it turned out to be wrong. It was registered as `x86_64-pc-msys` under enither the Windows System Variables and/or msys2's `.bashrc` variables. I've overridden that variable by entering `--host=x86_64-pc-mingw64` into the `configure` then it configured  perfecly fine.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. There is no need to remove -m64 from CFLAGS or ABI=64 from ./configure arguments, just had to append `--host=x86_64-pc-mingw64` (I was compiling GMP on Windows using msys2)